# Taking absolute square of the following term

Tags: complex, algebraic-manipulation

I have this equation and I wanted to find the absolute square of this term in Mathematica

$$ H_1 =  \left |  1 + j\; \left(\frac{ 2 \pi}{1-e^\lambda}\right) \right|^2   $$

I did this in mathematica

```
H1 = Abs[1 + 1*i*((2*Pi)/ (1 - e^(-\[Lambda])))]^2
```

which does not yield any result.

then I did this [image]

Can anyone help? As the absolute square is just square of real-term and imaginary term which should be simple. Solving this on paper is quite simple

$$ H_1 =  \left |  1 + j\; \left(\frac{ 2 \pi}{1-e^\lambda}\right) \right|^2   $$

$$ H_2 =  \left |  1 + \; \left(\frac{ j2 \pi}{e^{(-j2\pi)}-e^{(-j2\pi\lambda)}}\right) \right|^2   $$

---

Thank you very much, I made an edit in the question. Now I have H_2 as well, can you please look into H_2 at the end of the question and tell me how to calculate it's absolute square. My code for H_2 in Mathematica is

```
(ComplexExpand[#1, TargetFunctions -> {Re, Im}] & )[ Abs[1 + (I*2*Pi)/ ((2*Pi)/E^I - E^I*2*Pi* [Lambda])]^2] –
```

Comment: You seem to be implicitly assuming that $\lambda$ is real...

Comment: @J.M. YES, $\lambda$ is real.

Answer (score 4):

Imaginary unit is `I` , not i, exponential constant is `E`  , not e and use option for `ComplexExpand`

```
Abs[1 + (2 I π)/(1 - E^-λ)]^2 // 
   ComplexExpand[#, TargetFunctions -> {Re, Im}] &

(*   1 + (4 π^2)/(1 - E^-λ)^2   *)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I made an edit in the question. Now I have H_2 as well, can you please look into H_2 at the end of the question and tell me how to calculate it's absolute square. 

My code for H_2 in Mathematica is 

(ComplexExpand[#1, 
    TargetFunctions -> 
     {Re, Im}] & )[
  Abs[1 + (I*2*Pi)/
      ((2*Pi)/E^I - E^I*2*Pi*
        \[Lambda])]^2]

Comment: @good_omen92 - The code for `H2` should be `(ComplexExpand[#1, TargetFunctions -> {Re, Im}] &)[Abs[1 + (I*2*Pi)/(E^(I*2*Pi) - E^(I*2*Pi*\[Lambda]))]^2] // FullSimplify`

Comment: Did you miss negative signs in exponential power? Isn't that?

(ComplexExpand[#1, TargetFunctions -> {Re, Im}] &)[Abs[1 + (I*2*Pi)/(E^(-I*2*Pi) - E^(-I*2*Pi*\[Lambda]))]^2] // FullSimplify